# Error with cascading if statement

Tags: java

I have this if then statement I am working on and a part of it seem to not work. In the last part of my class the part that says math.random>.6666 the compiler gives me an error and says that it is not a statement I a not sure what is causing this.

```
 private static void createShapes() {
     for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        // Select a random color
        int red = generateRandomInt(0, 255);
        int green = generateRandomInt(0, 255);
        int blue = generateRandomInt(0, 255);
        Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);

        // Decide whether to create a circle or a rectangle
        if (Math.random() > 0&&Math.random()<=.3333333)  {
            // Generate a circle with a random size and position
            int diameter = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - diameter);
            int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - diameter);
            shapes[i] = new Circle(x, y, color, diameter);
        } else if (Math.random()>.3333333) {
            // Generate a rectangle with a random size and
            // position
            int width = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int height = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - width);
            int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - height);
            shapes[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, color, width, height);      
        } else   (Math.random()>.66666666666){
            int leng = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - leng);
            int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - leng);
            shapes[i] = new Triangle(x, y, color, leng);                      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you omitted the word "if" after "else".

Comment: Also, I don't think you want those four separate calls to `Math.random`.  I think you want to call it once and put the result in a local variable.  Otherwise you'll get many cases where none of the three blocks of code will be run.

Comment: hmm yes you are right so it is else if

Comment: how would I do put the result in a local variable and then if then?

Comment: would I do double a=math.random; then else if a>.666666

Comment: Yes, you could do that.  Don't forget the parentheses after `random`.  Maybe choose a better variable name too.

Comment: Another option would be to use and `int` variable, set it to `(int) Math.random() * 3` and use a `switch/case` for the three different shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new random number for every if statement.  You should create one variable.  In your current code, even after the `else if` fix, all those conditions could possibly be met, or even none at all.

```
 double random = Math.random();     

 if (random > 0 && random <=.3333333)  {
     // Generate a circle with a random size and position
     int diameter = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
     int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - diameter);
     int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - diameter);
     shapes[i] = new Circle(x, y, color, diameter);
 } else if (random >.3333333 && random < 0.666666) {
     // Generate a rectangle with a random size and
     // position
     int width = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
     int height = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
     int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - width);
     int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - height);
     shapes[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, color, width, height);

 } else {
     int leng = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
     int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - leng);
     int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - leng);
     shapes[i] = new Triangle(x, y, color, leng);                     
 }
```

You don't even need the last condition in the `else`, because if the other two conditions are not met, the last will automatically be met. All you need is `else`.

An even better design would me

```
if (random > 0.66666) {
   ...
}
else if (random > 0.33333){
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```

If the first condition is met, the other two won't perform. If the first condition is not met, and the second is met, the third will not perform. If the first two are not met, the third will perform.

Comment: I also added a preferred design style. Please accept answer if this solves your problem. I see you haven't accepted any of your past answers.

Comment: Yes I have accepted the answer. I would vote it up if my reputation allowed it.

Answer (score 2):

You have `else   (Math.random()>.66666666666){`

That won't compile.  Either you need an IF, or you need to remove the check on Math.Random().

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an if statement after the last else:

```
else if  (Math.random()>.66666666666){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code you've already written to make this much cleaner.  I'm assuming that your `generateRandomInt` method produces a number between its two parameters, inclusively (that is, both parameters are possible return values).

```
private static void createShapes() {
     for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        // Select a random color
        int red = generateRandomInt(0, 255);
        int green = generateRandomInt(0, 255);
        int blue = generateRandomInt(0, 255);
        Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
        int shapeType = generateRandomInt(0, 2);

        switch (shapeType) {

        case 0:
            // Generate a circle with a random size and position
            int diameter = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - diameter);
            int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - diameter);
            shapes[i] = new Circle(x, y, color, diameter);
            break;

        case 1:
            // Generate a rectangle with a random size and
            // position
            int width = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int height = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - width);
            int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - height);
            shapes[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, color, width, height);      
            break;

        case 2:
            int leng = generateRandomInt(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
            int x = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - leng);
            int y = generateRandomInt(0, WINDOW_SIZE - leng);
            shapes[i] = new Triangle(x, y, color, leng);                      
            break;
        }
    }
}
```